# Checkbox symbol for a to do list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, checkbox

I'm trying to create a to-do list application in JavaScript. Using HTML and CSS, I've created a checkmark button. The problem is that the checkmark button doesn't display when adding a new task, but the task is added. Can someone explain to me what's wrong and how it should be done?

I can not understand if my problem is from HTML or CSS or JavaScript.

**Code Snippet**

```js
let userinput = [];

function task() {
  const inputText = document.getElementById("inputbutton").value;

  // Check if inputText already exists in userinput array
  if (userinput.includes(inputText)) {
    alert("Already added");
    return; // Exit function early if inputText already exists
  }


  userinput.push(inputText);

  let tasklist = document.getElementById("tasklist");
  let listItem = document.createElement("li");
  listItem.textContent = inputText;
  tasklist.appendChild(listItem);

}

/*
I also tried this:
   let checkmarks = document.querySelectorAll('.container .checkmark');
    checkmarks.forEach(checkmark => {
        checkmark.style.display = 'block';
    });
*/
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

#inputbutton {
  color: hsl(210deg 100% 44%);
  ;
  border: 2px solid hsl(210deg 100% 44%);
  ;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background: transparent;
  max-width: 190px;
  margin-top: 4em;
  margin-left: 42em;
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 12px 8px 50px;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.input:active {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px #8707ff inset;
}

button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 11px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 0;
  background-color: hsl(210deg 100% 44%);
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 31ms cubic-bezier(.5, .7, .4, 1);
}

button:before {
  content: attr(alt);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  opacity: 1;
}

button:active {
  box-shadow: none;
  transform: translateY(7px);
  transition: 35ms cubic-bezier(.5, .7, .4, 1);
}

button:hover:before {
  transition: all .0s;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  opacity: 0;
}

button i {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-style: normal;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  opacity: 0;
}

button:hover i {
  transition: all .2s ease;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}

button:hover i:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.045s;
}

button:hover i:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: calc(0.045s * 3);
}

button:hover i:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: calc(0.045s * 4);
}

button:hover i:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: calc(0.045s * 5);
}

button:hover i:nth-child(6) {
  transition-delay: calc(0.045s * 6);
}

button:hover i:nth-child(7) {
  transition-delay: calc(0.045s * 7);
}

button:hover i:nth-child(8) {
  transition-delay: calc(0.045s * 8);
}

button:hover i:nth-child(9) {
  transition-delay: calc(0.045s * 9);
}

button:hover i:nth-child(10) {
  transition-delay: calc(0.045s * 10);
}


/* Hide the default checkbox */

.container input {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}


/* Create a custom checkbox */

.checkmark {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 1.3em;
  width: 1.3em;
  background-color: #2196F300;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}


/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */

.container input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}


/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  border: 0.1em solid black;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 1.05em;
  height: 1.05em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  transition: all 0.25s, border-width 0.1s;
}


/* Show the checkmark when checked */

.container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  left: 0.45em;
  top: 0.25em;
  width: 0.25em;
  height: 0.5em;
  border-color: #fff0 white white #fff0;
  border-width: 0 0.15em 0.15em 0;
  border-radius: 0em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<input tyoe="text" id="inputbutton"></input>
<button class="addtask" onclick="task()" alt="Add task">
        <i>A</i>
        <i>d</i>
        <i>d</i>
        <i>&nbsp;</i>
        <i>t</i>
        <i>a</i>
        <i>s</i>
        <i>k</i>
      </button>
<label class="container">
        <input type="checkbox"/>
        <div class="checkmark"></div>
      </label>
<ul id="tasklist"></ul>
```

Comment: Since this isn't a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I refuse to try.

Comment: I can run your code, but it's not clear what you want it to do. Please edit your question to better explain your desired result and contrast that with the actual result you are seeing.

Comment: You have a typo in `input tyoe="text"`.

Comment: @ITgoldman I was responding to a now deleted comment :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A todo list is a classic, and also this technique for duplicating *templates*. Just copy the html and set the `innerHTML` of the target.

```js
let userinput = [];


function task() {
  const inputText = document.getElementById("inputbutton").value;

  // Check if inputText already exists in userinput array
  if (userinput.includes(inputText)) {
    alert("Already added");
    return; // Exit function early if inputText already exists
  }

  var html = document.querySelector("#myTaskTemplate").innerHTML

  userinput.push(inputText);

  let tasklist = document.getElementById("tasklist");
  let listItem = document.createElement("li");
  // listItem.textContent = inputText;
  listItem.innerHTML = html
  
  // after applying html, you can adjust elements or attach events
  listItem.querySelector(".checkmark").textContent = inputText

  tasklist.appendChild(listItem);

}

/*
I also tried this:
   let checkmarks = document.querySelectorAll('.container .checkmark');
    checkmarks.forEach(checkmark => {
        checkmark.style.display = 'block';
    });
*/
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

#inputbutton {
  color: hsl(210deg 100% 44%);
  border: 2px solid hsl(210deg 100% 44%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background: transparent;
  max-width: 190px;
  margin-top: 4em;
  margin-left: 42em;
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 12px 8px 50px;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.input:active {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px #8707ff inset;
}

button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 11px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 0;
  background-color: hsl(210deg 100% 44%);
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 31ms cubic-bezier(.5, .7, .4, 1);
}

button:before {
  content: attr(alt);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  opacity: 1;
}

button:active {
  box-shadow: none;
  transform: translateY(7px);
  transition: 35ms cubic-bezier(.5, .7, .4, 1);
}

button:hover:before {
  transition: all .0s;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  opacity: 0;
}

button i {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-style: normal;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  opacity: 0;
}

button:hover i {
  transition: all .2s ease;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}

button:hover i:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.045s;
}

button:hover i:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: calc(0.045s * 3);
}

button:hover i:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: calc(0.045s * 4);
}

button:hover i:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: calc(0.045s * 5);
}

button:hover i:nth-child(6) {
  transition-delay: calc(0.045s * 6);
}

button:hover i:nth-child(7) {
  transition-delay: calc(0.045s * 7);
}

button:hover i:nth-child(8) {
  transition-delay: calc(0.045s * 8);
}

button:hover i:nth-child(9) {
  transition-delay: calc(0.045s * 9);
}

button:hover i:nth-child(10) {
  transition-delay: calc(0.045s * 10);
}


/* Hide the default checkbox */

.container input {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}


/* Create a custom checkbox */

.checkmark {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 1.3em;
  width: 1.3em;
  background-color: #2196F300;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}


/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */

.container input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}


/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  border: 0.1em solid black;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 1.05em;
  height: 1.05em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  transition: all 0.25s, border-width 0.1s;
}


/* Show the checkmark when checked */

.container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  left: 0.45em;
  top: 0.25em;
  width: 0.25em;
  height: 0.5em;
  border-color: #fff0 white white #fff0;
  border-width: 0 0.15em 0.15em 0;
  border-radius: 0em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputbutton">
<button class="addtask" onclick="task()" alt="Add task">
  <i>A</i>
  <i>d</i>
  <i>d</i>
  <i>&nbsp;</i>
  <i>t</i>
  <i>a</i>
  <i>s</i>
  <i>k</i>
</button>
<div id="myTaskTemplate" style="display:none">
  <label class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div class="checkmark"></div>
  </label>
</div>
<ul id="tasklist"></ul>
```